# How to disable anti-aliasing in QGIS export (pyqgis)

Tags: python-3.x, qgis

I'm trying to save a print layout as BMP in QGIS through python code, but want to turn of antialiasing and can't seem to figure out how to do it

```
def saveImage(self, layout, filename="defaultexport", extension=".bmp"):
    """Saves given layout as an image"""
    filefolder = get_save_location()
    filepath = os.path.join(filefolder, filename + extension)

    if not os.path.isdir(filefolder):
        os.makedirs(filefolder)


    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    context = QgsLayoutRenderContext(layout)
    context.setFlag(context.FlagAntialiasing, False)


    export_settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
    export_settings.generateWorldFile = False
    export_settings.dpi = 25
    export_settings.flags = context.FlagAntialiasing
    result = exporter.exportToImage(filepath, export_settings)
```

Is what I have. I have no idea what I'm doing with the QgsLayoutRenderContext, but it's about the only thing that seemed like it might do it. Saving manually and turning of the AA setting in save dialog works fine, but I need to do it through pyqgis

Answer (score 1):

Revisting this project knowing some more Python and PyQt5 stuff this was an easy one

```
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    context = QgsLayoutRenderContext(layout)
    context.setFlag(context.FlagAntialiasing, False)

    export_settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
    export_settings.generateWorldFile = False
    export_settings.dpi = 25
    export_settings.flags = context.flags()
    result = exporter.exportToImage(self.filepath, export_settings)
```

Needed to use context.flags()